# is there a way to provide variable in slicing list in jinja?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

how can I do slicing in jinja by passing a variable for example id?

```
{% for record in result[id:id+2]%}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: why can't you send sliced result into render (`template.render(result=result[id:id+2])`)?